# MS Search Server - ConfigurationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, moss, search-engine

Im getting a ConfigurationException whenever i try to perform  QueryService.Query or QueryService.ExQuery. Same goes when i do GetSearchMetadata().

I can however do a GetPortalSearchInfo() and Status() without problems.

Any hint of what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a missing hotfix:

windows6.1-kb976462-ia64.msu